# Random password generate

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have requirement to generate a 8 digit random password which must contains letters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9). Am using following function to generate my password.It was working for me, once i noticed some passwords are letters only eg "WaIoGarQ". How to improve my code to make sure which include both letters and numbers.

```
 _makePwd = function () {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

            for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }
            return text;
        }
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: http://fent.github.io/randexp.js/

Comment: Forcing your password to contain a certain number of numbers does not make it more random or less predictable than letting it be truly random from the entire list of your possible characters.

Comment: @jfriend00 found a npm here https://github.com/bermi/password-generator but struggling to write a regular expression which match my requirement could you please check.  var random_pwd = generatePassword(8, false, /\w/);

Comment: For a password you need to use cryptographic functions such as `window.crypto`. [Check out my analysis of the LastPass generator](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/77408/8340) although this falls back onto `Math.random()` :s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, I have considered maximum of 4 numbers, you can change it in letterUsed variable. You can add Capital letters as well in array

```
function getAlphaNumeric(){
  var arr =['a','b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g','h','i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n','o','p','q', 'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'],
 letterUsed=0,numberUsed=0, maxNum =Math.ceil(Math.random()*4), maxLetter = 8-maxNum,i=0, randomStr='';
 for(;i<8;i++){
  if((Math.floor(Math.random()*2) === 0 && numberUsed <maxNum) || letterUsed>=maxLetter ){
      randomStr += Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
      numberUsed++;
  }else{    
    randomStr += arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)];
    letterUsed++;
  }
}
return randomStr;
}
getAlphaNumeric();
```

Comment: Tried you code, but its generating number only passwords

Comment: @Dibish That was myb bad, I have edited the code, please check.

Comment: Thank yo for your edit, now i have included Uppercase letters in Array, also changed 26 to 52 to include uppercase letters. randomStr += arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*52)];